# Duda comparación dos hashCode de dos Objetos y como uno de ellos toma el valor del otro

Tags: java

ante todo disculpas por esta duda si fuera demasiado básica, pero "en principio" no me la esperaba tener a estas alturas.

Creo una clase propia con sus correspondientes atributos e instancio dos objetos de esta clase.
Cuando imprimo por consola el hashCode de estos objetos, lógicamente me muestra dos valores distintos.

La duda me surge cuando los igualo:

Objeto1=Objeto2

Al volver a imprimir por consola el valor del hashCode de estos dos objetos, veo que los dos me muestran el valor de hashCode que anteriormente mostraba Objeto1.

No deberían mostrar el hashCode que anteriormente mostraba Objeto2, ya que Objeto1 "toma el valor" de Objeto2?

Saludos y gracias

Edito para incluir el código.

```
public class Comparacion {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Objeto obj1 = new Objeto("Objeto1");
    Objeto obj2 = new Objeto("Objeto2");

    obj1 = obj2;//comentando y descomentando se pueden ver los cambios


    System.out.println(obj1.hashCode());
    System.out.println(obj2.hashCode());

    }

}

class Objeto {

private String nombre;

public Objeto(String nombre) {

    this.nombre = nombre;

    }

}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes. ¿Podrías poner el código con el que obtienes ese resultado en la pregunta? Se me hace un escenario muy raro

Comment: Hola, gracias, acabo de incluirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Pues si estas haciendo solamente la asignación de `Objeto1=Objeto2` el resultado debería ser que ambas impresiones del hash code sea la que tiene Objeto2 ya que ahora `Objeto1` hace referencia a `Objeto2`, como se ve en la siguiente prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos ver al principio cada objeto tiene un código hash diferente, luego de hacer la asignación `o1=o2` se imprime el  mismo código hash para `o1` y `o2` que es el mismo código que ha tenido `o2`.

**Actualización**:

He hecho otra prueba basandome en el código que has compartido, como puedes ver en esta ejecución al hacer la asignación `obj1=obj2` el primer código hash generado en realidad pertenece a `obj2` y no al objeto `obj1` original, este último valor lo podemos ver en la tercera impresión de consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, si eso es lo que esperaba encontrar yo.. Pero utilizando eclipse, en la ventana de consola, no se asignan estos valores

Comment: No estoy seguro pero creo que ese comportamiento tiene que ver con el orden de ejecución de los métodos. Es decir cuando llamas por primera vez al método hashCode (sin haber realizado la asignación obj1 = obj2) se genera el numero código hash X, luego cuando llamas al método hashCode para el segundo objeto se genera el código Y. Lo mismo sucede cuando haces la asignación obj1=obj2 y llamas al método hashCode, primero se genera el código X, pero este en realidad pertece a obj2 y no a obj1 original. Puedes ver la prueba que hice en mi respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Gracias! Parece que si, que tiene que ver con el espacio en memoria que se les va asignando a los objetos conforme se ejecuta el programa. Lo que he estado viendo mientras me informaba sobre esto, es que normalmente se sobrescribe el método hashCode y se relaciona el hashCode del objeto, no tanto al del propio objeto, sino que en el cuerpo del método sobrescrito, he visto que se utiliza un atributo del propio objeto (el hashCode del atributo) para relacionarlo con el del objeto.                                                                Ej: hashCode Objeto = nombre.hashCode*7